# How do I stop programs opening on startup

Tags: startup, automatic

For some reason every time I reboot my system a few programs open automatically.  I've tried closing them down and then rebooting the machine, but they still pop up again afterwards. 
Does anyone know how to stop this, so that whenever the system is rebooted I get a clear desktop with no open programs?

Many thanks.

P.s.
The main culprits are search monkey, transmission and my file browser (it says it's just called Files)

Answer (score 2):

Open the Dash and search *STARTUP APPLICATIONS*. Click on the cog wheel on the top right corner of your screen and choose *STARTUP APPLICATIONS* or type *STARTUP* in the Dash. Deselect the programs you don't want to open at boot time. 
If you are an advanced user, you can edit the

> ~/.config/autostart

file with the parameter

> X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled = false